# How to get queued Messages when using ServiceThrottlingBehavior

Tags: c#, wcf

I have WCF service which is regulated with helps ServiceThrottlingBehavior. I use property MaxConcurrentCalls which restricts calls, but I need know how many calls stopped/waiting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in performance counters for queued requests in WCF so you would have to use those from ASP.NET if your service is hosted under IIS.